# Blaze Data field map throws TypeError

Tags: python, blaze

I have recently started moving my data exploration code set from `pandas` to `blaze`.  I am running into the following issue.

Assume:

```
from blaze import *

s = Data([(1, 'Alice', 100),
...           (2, 'Bob', -200),
...           (3, 'Charlie', 300),
...           (4, 'Denis', 400),
...           (5, 'Edith', -500)],
...          fields=['id', 'name', 'balance'])
```

we can using `pandas.DataFrame` via `into` readily compute something like:

```
into(pd.DataFrame,s).balance.apply(abs)
```

However, I am having serious difficulties trying to do:

```
s.balance.map(abs,schema='{b: int64}')
```

throws a `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'int'` among other things.

This issue seems related to [Best approach to apply a function to a column or create a new column by applying a function to another one?](https://github.com/blaze/blaze/issues/513) which is closed, so I am not sure where to turn.

ps: if you feel this is trivial and want to mark the question down, please also provide a complete working answer.

Comment: I would like to point out that `s = transform(s, b = abs(s.balance))` does the right thing.  But in this question I was using the `abs` function as an easy to understand placeholder for any function acting on one variable/field.  The issue remains as,  `def FindC(word): return word.lower().find('c')` can't be used as in `transform(s,hasC = FindC(s.name))`.  Doing so I get `AttributeError: 'Field' object has no attribute 'lower'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing `'int64'` as the `datashape`, rather than passing in a value for `schema`. It's the second keyword argument, so you don't need to name it. The following:

```
from blaze import *
s = Data([(1, 'Alice', 100),
          (2, 'Bob', -200),
          (3, 'Charlie', 300),
          (4, 'Denis', 400),
          (5, 'Edith', -500)],
          fields=['id', 'name', 'balance'])
s.balance.map(abs, 'int64')
```

works for me, and produces:

```
   balance
0      100
1      200
2      300
3      400
4      500
```

p.s. Though importing everything from blaze seems to be clobbering the built-in `abs` with `blaze.expr.abs`, I don't think that matters.

Comment: I am still getting the long `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'int'`

Comment: I am using `blaze` version `0.9.1`.  What version are you using?

Comment: I'm using `0.9.0`. I found that I was also getting an error after creating the `Data` instance with a `list`, like you did above. I played around a little, and I think the `datashape` argument needs to be used, rather than `schema`. I will update the answer.